# How to scale 2 axes on a certain date with dimple/d3?

Tags: d3.js, charts, dimple.js

I have a chart that receives 2 sets of data and draws a chart with 2 axes, both visible.
I have provided a simple [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/buu2xLL7/) for a visual example.

Relevant parts of code:

> var x = myChart.addTimeAxis('x', 'Date', '%d-%m-%Y', '%d-%m-%Y');
>       x.showGridlines = true;
>       x.addOrderRule('Date');

```
var y1 = myChart.addMeasureAxis('y', 'Total Cost');
y1.showGridlines = true;

var y2 = myChart.addMeasureAxis('y', 'Total Value');
y2.tickFormat = '.1f';
y2.showGridlines = true;

var s1 = myChart.addSeries('Statistic Type', dimple.plot.line, [x, y1]);
s1.data = first_series;

var s2 = myChart.addSeries('Statistic Type', dimple.plot.line, [x, y2]);
s2.data = second_series;
```

What I want to do is scale both axes in a way that on a certain date (e.g 01-10-2014), the point is on the same level on the height of the chart. in the [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/r6j8wzs6zlvz511/Capture.PNG?dl=0) I provided an example on how it should look like (the date drawn by me is approximated :D)

Thanks,
Alexandra

Comment: The basic functionality you need to use is probably overrideMin and  overrideMax on the y axes, however I don't think it's going to be easy, it feels to me like it will be a non-linear equation.

Comment: But why if I have y2.overrideMax = 111.0, the value is not really overriden and my axis maximum value goes a bit higher?

Comment: There's already an issue in git hub for this. At the moment dimple still applies it's rounding logic to overridden axes. Your case is quite unusual it would probably be best to use raw d3 instead of a higher level api like dimple.